# Can 301 redirects be done for some pages from old domain to page on new domain. Old domain will remain UP

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, search-results, link-juice

Recently(couple of days ago), we used the `url removal tool in google webmaster` to remove some for our existing pages on our `.com` domain but actually we wanted to pass the link juice for those pages from our current `.com` domain to the new `.co` domain.

So I wanted to know whether doing a `301 redirect` for SOME pages only (not the whole site) from our current domain to the corresponding page on new domain will successfully pass the link juice for those pages onto the new URL's(pages).

Please note the current `.com` will NOT BE GOING DOWN, IT WILL REMAIN UP. It's just that we would like to move some pages to our new `.co` domain and pass over their link juice if that's possible/ will work?

Since I have already used the URL removal tool, if I "Reinclude" those removed one using the "Reinclude" button in GWT, will those page regain it's position in SERP and then do a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

301 redirects work per page and not per domain, so if you 301 redirect a page Google index algorithm will recognise that the new page is replacing the old one.

However that doesn't mean that the new page will be indexed exactly with the same score as the old one. 301 redirects pass the **score** from the **number/quality of links pointing to page**, but this is just one of the many factors that determine how high page scores for a specific search, made from a specific user.

There's many **other factors** that are as important, including speed of the new page, user experience, reputation of the new domain name and of course behaviour of the users when they click the page from a specific search.

Comment: To redirect just one page you would use a line like this in *.htaccess* in the root directory of `example.com`: `Redirect permanent /dir/page.html http://example.co/dir/page.html`